# Python pivot with column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am new to python and need a help for small pivot function

I have a table with data present in the format above

```
order_id    primary_dish    primary_cat dish_id order_date  average_adoption
927852        54438             1         54465   2016-12-11    37.5
927852        54438             1         54443   2016-12-11    37.5
927852        54453             1         54453   2016-12-11    25.61
```

Using pandas i have pivoted the above table using dish_id But i want to replace the values which are getting lised as NAN with average_adotion columns which i am not able to do

Currently getting output as below

```
order_id primary_dish primary_cat   54438   54443   54453   54465
  927852      54438          1       NaN    1.0      1.0    1.0
  927852      54443          1        1.0   NaN      1.0    1.0
  927852      54453          1        1.0   1.0      NaN    1.0
```

Pivot function

```
dish.pivot_table(index=['order_id', 'primary_dish', 'primary_cat'],
                 columns='dish_id',values=['average_adoption'], aggfunc='size'
                ).reset_index()
```

Output should look like

```
order_id primary_dish primary_cat   54438   54443   54453   54465
  927852      54438          1       37.5   1.0      1.0    1.0
  927852      54443          1       1.0    25.61    1.0    1.0
  927852      54453          1       1.0    1.0      25.61  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First pivot and dont `reset_index` for later alignment:

```
df = dish.pivot_table(index=['order_id', 'primary_dish', 'primary_cat'],
                               columns='dish_id',values=['average_adoption'], aggfunc='size')
```

Create Series by `mean` with same index like `pivot_table`:

```
s = dish.groupby(['order_id','primary_dish','primary_cat'])['average_adoption'].mean()
```

Replace `NaN`s by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html):

```
print (df.mask(df.isnull(), s, axis=0).reset_index())
dish_id  order_id  primary_dish  primary_cat  54443  54453  54465
0          927852         54438            1   1.00   37.5   1.00
1          927852         54453            1  25.61    1.0  25.61
```

Also should be working (but for me not in pandas `0.20.3`):

```
print (df.fillna(s))
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael
I keep on getting 
"ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names"
error while using the methord above

Comment: There has to be some problem with data, is possible share your code with data?